# Как мне получить координаты когда я убрал палец с экрана Google map

Tags: android

Вопрос в следующем: мне даны координаты  в центре карты, эти координаты  я отправлю  в геокодер и получаю адрес. Использую  следующий код для получения центра карты,  но проблема в том, что получаю координаты даже при мелких изменения, и тем самым превышаю лимит запросов. Как мне получить координаты, когда убрал палец с экрана?

```
            @Override
            public void onCameraChange(CameraPosition cameraPosition) {
                LatLng center = mMap.getCameraPosition().target;
                double latitude = center.latitude;
                double longitude = center.longitude;});
```

Comment: Я думаю, что запрашивать координаты у камеры можно сколько угодно, а вот адрес не так часто. А почему бы вам не повесить обработчик OnTouchListener, в котором выполнять действия после ACTION_UP с последними получеными координатами из onCameraChange?!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Виталий Обидейко 5 ноя в 12:29
Я думаю, что запрашивать координаты у камеры можно сколько угодно, а вот адрес не так часто. А почему бы вам не повесить обработчик OnTouchListener, в котором выполнять действия после ACTION_UP с последними получеными координатами из onCameraChange?! –